# Assembly data tabel in rodata section vs text section

Tags: assembly

i have a question about definiing data-table label .... for example, for this data table:

```
DD      214125
DD      51224
DD      63424
DD      6456457
DD      575745
```

now we can defined this table in 2 ways... one using a label and define it in '.text' section like this

```
section '.text' executable

public my_data

my_data:
    DD      214125
    DD      51224
    DD      63424
    DD      6456457
    DD      575745
```

our we can define it in 'rodata' section (static const section)

```
section '.rodata' 

my_data:
    DD      214125
    DD      51224
    DD      63424
    DD      6456457
    DD      575745
```

i know that rodata is something like `static const int my_data[] = {...}` but what about the first one ? (defining data table in '.text' section)

for example, i have 10 functions that are using this tabel .... i can access to this data table in that functions just with using [my_data + ...] but i can't understand how that data-table works in the (text section) !!

the second one (rodata section) is clear !!!! data will loaded into the memory and function gets the data but in the first one (text section) how function get the data from my_data tabel ? !!!!

Comment: If it is in the text segment, the systems would prefer pc-relative addressing to compute the effective address.  If it is in the data segment it will either use absolute addressing or data segment offset, depending on the system.  The rodata section *on some systems* is appended to the text section at the time that executable is constructed, so the system could also use pc-relative addressing for that (otherwise more like the data).

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Both the text section and the rodata section are loaded into memory (typically adjacent to each other), so the way that the code accesses the table is the same for both.

Comment: I assume rodata is non-executable section, while text is in an executable section.

Comment: @ErikEidt - I'm not aware of any MOV or LEA with PC relative addressing.

Comment: @rcgldr as this question is not tagged with a specific architecture, which one might you be speaking to?  On x86, you use might the `CS:` segment override prefix.  On x64 you say something like this: `mov eax, dword ptr [rel variablelabel]` where the "rel" tells it to use pc-relative addressing.  Many other architectures also have pc-relative addressing even for loads & stores.  MIPS only has pc-relative for branches, but RISC V has special instruction `AUIPC` that does pc-relative addressing for an `LEA`-type instruction.  ARM does pc-relative addressing for loads & stores.

Comment: @rcgldr: Erik is talking about non-x86 with small-displacement PC-relative addressing, so the assembler can only use it if it knows the distance at *assemble* time to be sure it will fit.  This is why ARM often uses "literal pools" of constant data between functions.  But on x86-64, any addressing mode can use PC-relative, usually called RIP-relative on x86-64, with a 32-bit relative displacement.  So it's usable for any section.  (x86 assemblers default to a "small" memory model where everything is within +-2GiB of each other.)

Comment: @ErikEidt: Modern MIPS also has `auipc`, I think.  Like MIPS32 or at least MIPS32r6.  Along with longer-range PC-relative unconditional jumps, I think.  (Traditional MIPS `j` jump instructions are semi-absolute, replacing the low 28 bits of PC, unlike I-type `b` branch instructions that add a signed displacement.)

Comment: @ErikEidt: you would only possibly need a `CS:` override in segmented code.  Normal 32-bit x86 code (e.g. under Linux, MacOS, Windows, etc.) uses a flat memory model, and x86-64 requires a flat memory model.  So CS and DS always have the same base.  And yes, in NASM syntax `[rel some_label]` is a PC-relative load.

Comment: @ErikEidt - I was thinking X86 32 bit mode, not X86-X64 (64 bit) mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes, I did mention `AUIPC` in my comment above (RISC V, i.e. modern MIPS ;).

Comment: @ErikEidt: lolwut?  RISC-V is a separate ISA *inspired* by MIPS.  I'm talking about real MIPS that still calls itself MIPS, e.g. where I-type instructions have 16-bit immediates, not 12 for RISC-V.  Apparently MIPS `auipc` was new in [MIPS32r6 in 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS32/MIPS64_Release_6) - "PC-relative load instructions, as well as address generation with large (PC-relative) offsets." Also checked an ISA manual PDF.  MIPS32r6 did rearrange some opcodes so it's not even binary compatible with previous MIPS, but it's still MIPS and definitely not RISC-V.

Comment: @PeterCordes, well, who knew!  RISC V has that same mnemonic, too -- probably very similar.  And yes, despite total incompatibility, to one way of looking at it, RISC V is an improvement on MIPS.